# How to deploy docker app to offline server

Tags: docker, docker-compose

What is the best way to deploy an application on to a server that has no internet access.

I have built a Python Flask Application which has been built with docker using the following docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.7"

services:

  flask:
    build:
      context: ./app1
      args:
        - "proxy=this is where the proxy is"
    container_name: flask
    restart: always
    image: app1
    environment:
      - APP_NAME=TFI
    expose:
      - 8000
    volumes:
      - c:/temp_files:/temp_files
      - c:/test_files:/test_files
      - /home/mnt-data/temp-files
      - /home/mnt-data/test-files

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    image: nginx
    container_name: nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "443:443"
```

I then have built this using `docker-compose build` and have tested it using `docker-compose up` and all works as expected. The question is then, how to I move the built application to a server that has no internet access?

I migrated the built images using `docker image save` and migrated the tar file over to the server and then used `docker load` but when using `docker run` to run the built image it doesn't seem to work. Maybe I just don't understand how docker works.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

- if it is only just one server. You [save](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/) the images from an online machine and [load](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/load/) on the offline server.
- Any other case. Use a private registry to serve the images from inside your offline environment.

Comment: which is what I'm currently doing but it when running the image is doesnt seem to work. Should I be using docker-compose to run the image or just docker.

Comment: I guess also, are the config setting used in the docker-compose.yml saved in to the the built image?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote the bad command it is not `import` but `load`. I'm modifying my answer.

Comment: I did specify that I'm currently doing this but it doesn't work. How do I run the app. Normally I would use docker-compose but I'm guessing I don't to just run the image, but what about all of the config data that is stored in the docker compose?

Comment: I recomend to not build the docker image on the docker-compose. Just build the images on your laptop copy to the server and modify the docker compose to use the images instead to build them